# Cannot list network interfaces in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: networking, windows, ifconfig, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to list all network interfaces in Windows Subsystem for Linux shell but I got this error message:

```
Warning: cannot open /proc/net/dev (File o directory non esistente). Limited output.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It is probably not yet implemented. Since `/dev` is a special file system created by the Linux kernel on demand, every part of it needs to be implemented in the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere further with this?  Allegedly, you can run apache under WSL (implying networking works?), but I cannot find any info how networking for WSL is supposed to be configured.  Or official documentation on what all WSL supports for that matter.

Comment: Hi Brian, I haven't any news on this... Vote my question, maybe it will attract other user that can suggest us something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making my comment a proper answer, as of the day of this writing, the feature is probably not yet implemented.

Since `/dev` is a special file system created by the Linux kernel on demand, every part of it needs to be implemented in the Windows Subsystem for Linux

Comment: Thanks! I cannot vote your answer because I haven't the appropriate reputation. If you consider good my question, please vote we and then when I will have the right reputation, I'll vote your answer.